# Can I use a buck converter and a 12 V adaptor to create a 5 V and a 12 V circuit?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, dc-dc-converter, step-down

I have a microcontroller that is powered by 5 V and some solenoids that need 12 V. At the moment I power the solenoids using a 12 V adapter and switch them on and off through MOSFETs which are in turn switched on and off by the microcontroller.

The microcontroller is powered by a separate 5 V power source which means I have two power sources now. Ideally I would like to be able to power the microcontroller using the 12 V adapter so I only have to work with one power source.

Now I read somewhere that with a buck convertor, you can step down voltage. For example, 12 V to 5 V. So I understand how I can create a 5 V circuit. But the thing is that I need both 12 V and 5 V. So in a sense, I want to create two sub-circuits (if you can call it that), 12 V and 5 V, using only a 12 V adapter.

Can someone answer the following question?

1. Is this possible using a buck converter?
2. If so, would you recommend this approach? Is there a more efficient way of achieving this?
3. How is this usually done in professional applications? For example, a DVD player. The smaller electrical components in a DVD player almost certainly need a lower voltage than the little motor that spins the DVD disk. However, I only see one power inlet. So this seems like a problem that was fixed a long time ago.
4. Can someone draw a little schematic showing how each component would be wired?

Comment: Sure you can. It's very commonly done with a buck converter.

Comment: That is great to hear. How would you wire each component? Do you simply put the buck convertor in parralel to the 12v section of the circuit?

Comment: Note that if you are using an Arduino (clone) instead of a bare microcontroller, there usually already is a voltage regulator on board, sometimes even a switching DC/DC converter that will take 12 V as input. Worth checking.

Comment: That is very convenient. Thank you for the information. I am however looking for a solution that would use a bare microcontroller. But this might come in handy in the future.

Comment: if you had a 12V fan and a 12V solenoid how would you wire them into the circuit? you'd just put them in parallel, right? same thing

Comment: In case of the example you give with the two 12V components, I would indeed put them in parallel. So it sounds right that you would be able to do the same with a buck convertor. However, I don't really know how a buck convertor works. For some reason I just assumed that the buck convertor would draw all the power from the power source and thus convert all of the power into 5V, leaving none for the 12V section. So am I correct to assume that the buck convertor only draws power whenever the load behind the convertor draws any power?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, possible and commonly done.
2. Yes, good approach. Less efficient approaches but also simpler and cheaper are just linear regulators.
3. If you are making a device and need a power supply anyway, the power supply can be designed to have multiple outputs. Or a boost or buck converter for converting a single voltage up or down. Or linear regulators.
4. It depends what components you use. You can design the converter from scratch or buy a module so no schematic can be given. Basic rule is, 12V in, 5V out.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is good to hear that the approach can work and is indeed a decent solution. Concerning the schematic, they would just need to include the components I mentioned in my original question. So the 12V power source, the buck convertor, the microcontroller, the MOSFET and solenoid. I am mainly interested in seeing how each component is connected to the other components. So for example, no need to worry about the different ports on the microcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

1. Of course it is possible and more expensive to use a buck converter
2. In practice I believe the use of voltage regulators is far more common, although generally less efficient than buck converters.

   The linear regulators have low efficiency 50-70% and the switching ones >70%, depending on the input voltage and load

   Also note a drawback of switching regulators is that they may cause EMI, which also stands for buck converters
3. Professional AC powered devices usually have a self contained highly efficient PSU which you can buy separately. This way you minimize EMI problems while achieving extremely high efficiency >90%. Battery powered devices on the other hand rely on voltage regulators.
4. From their respective datasheets here is the typical L7805 (linear regulator priced less than 1$) application
   [image: L78XX application]

and here is the typical LM2576 (switching regulator priced above 5$) application
[image: LM2576 application]

Comment: Thanks you evfokas for your answer and the schematics. Very usefull. A question regarding answer 3.  You mention that professional AC powered devices usually have a self contained  PSU. Does this mean that these PSUs have different outputs with different voltages. So for example, 12V and 5V?

Comment: A linear regulator's efficiency is slightly lower than the output voltage over the input voltage. That's worse than 50% for 12 V to 5 V. You can buy switching regulator modules that you can just plug in exactly like a linear regulator, and that get efficiencies better than 90%. Trust me, linear regulators are not worth using anymore for anything that isn't noise-sensitive.